# Remove empty lines in Netbeans 7.x

Tags: php, netbeans, line-breaks, code-formatting

Is there any plugin, macro or built-in function that can remove empty or redundant empty lines in Netbeans 7.2 (PHP bundle, Windows 7)? Due to different line-break formats in my upload and download process (Win <> Unix, via FileZilla and Netbeans), many PHP files doubled (even quadrupled) their line breaks.

[image: Double line breaks in PHP file]

I could remove them *file by file* using PSPad - but I am looking for an automatic or batch-capable solution. I can accept an external tool if available.

**Edit**: I know about the `Source > Format` helper, but there are no settings to remove blank lines.

Comment: it's worth pointing out the Netbeans 7.3 was released recently. I don't suppose it'll make any difference to this question, but you might want to upgrade anyway -- it has some good enhancements for PHP devs.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can do this with a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) + and a replacement. Do this in an editor window *or* in the project (*or* files) directory tree:

- Ctrl + H
- Check "Regular Expression"
- Search for `\n\n`
- Replace with `\n`
- Click "Replace all" until all lines are deleted

If you want to keep a blank line you should:

- Search for `\n\n\n`
- Replace with `\n\n`

If you want to replace consecutive lines that are not empty but contain *whitespaces only* you should:

- Search for `\n[\t\r]+$\n`
- Replace with `\n`

Comment: Works great, I can even choose a folder in the project tree, hit `CTRL-H` and apply the pattern to multiple files. I added a second expression to your answer - for empty lines with whitespaces.

Comment: It should be part of netbeans autoformat; other editor has it :(

Answer (score 13):

Try this one...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (find) in Netbeans as Regular Expression:

```
\n\s*(\n)
```

and Replace All by

```
$1
```

Answer (score 9):

In NetBeans 7.3 (I'm not sure about the earlier version, it should be available in 7.x)

Automatic removal:

> Tools > Options > Editor > On Save > **Remove Trailing Whitespace**:

you can choose from: "*None / All Lines / Modified Lines Only*"

Manual way:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: it does not remove the empty blank lines if there is too many blank lines (\n)

Comment: Otherwise you wouldn't be able to insert intentionally empty lines to visually separate your code. This function is just for unification of lines endings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is one and this is a very important feature indeed.
It depends on your settings but by default you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or find it in the context menu: Source > Format.

You can setup your own style for formating here: **Tools > Options > Formatting**. You can set this for all languages or individualy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - although you're basically right, there are no settings to remove blank lines. `Source > Format` was the place I hoped to get lucky, but there is nothing that does correct my line problem.

Comment: The solution provided by Code-Source is fine. But nonetheless if you format the code (click in the editor window and press Alt+Shift+F) it actually does automatically adjust / remove indents and whitespace. At least in my netbeans editor this is the case.

Comment: works for me!!! excellent